# Hide all elements based on the item selected on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my html:

```
<div id="drinks">
    <select id="test">
        <option data-tab="Coffee">Coffee</option>
        <option data-tab="Cold Drinks">Cold Drinks</option>
        <option data-tab="Hot Drinks">Hot Drinks</option>
    </select>
    <div class="section-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <section class="Coffee">
                <h3>Coffee </h3>
                <h4>Coffee Flavor</h4>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="Cold Drinks">
                <h3>Cold Drink</h3>
                <h4>Cold Drink</h4>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="Hot Drinks">
                <h3>Hot Drink</h3>
                <h4>Hot Drink</h4>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").on('load change', function() {  
        $("#test option").each(function() {
            $("#drinks ." + $(this).val()).hide();
        })
        $("#drinks ." + $(this).val()).show();
    }).change();
});
```

I want to only show the class that matches the dropdown data-tab value.
So if coffee is selected only coffee's h3 and h4 tag should be displayed. Similarly for other drop-down. What am i doing wrong ?
Here is the link to my fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/mmaharjan/onbusdhv/

Comment: Well for starters you forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle. Second, a space between class names denotes separate classes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make some markup changes to make it easy.

Like use `value` in the `option` to store the option's value, also in the section use an attribute to store the type. If you use `value` in options, you can easily get the current value by reading the `select`'s value. If you use class in the `section` then `[space]` is considered as a separator in class, so `Cold Drinks` will mean 2 classes `Cold` and `Drinks`, so it will much easy to use a attribute selector(Though you can use `class` attribute also with attribute selector, it will be better to use another attribute)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test").on('load change', function() {
    $('#drinks .section-wrapper > section').hide().filter('[data-type="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drinks">
  <select id="test">
    <option value="Coffee">Coffee</option>
    <option value="Cold Drinks">Cold Drinks</option>
    <option value="Hot Drinks">Hot Drinks</option>
  </select>
  <div class="section-wrapper">
    <section data-type="Coffee">
      <h3>Coffee </h3>
      <h4>Coffee Flavor</h4>
    </section>
    <section data-type="Cold Drinks">
      <h3>Cold Drink</h3>
      <h4>Cold Drink</h4>
    </section>
    <section data-type="Hot Drinks">
      <h3>Hot Drink</h3>
      <h4>Hot Drink</h4>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this following code

HTML

```
<div id="drinks">
      <select id="test">
        <option data-tab="Coffee">Coffee</option>
        <option data-tab="ColdDrinks">Cold Drinks</option>
        <option data-tab="HotDrinks">Hot Drinks</option>
      </select>
      <div class="section-wrapper">
        <section class="Coffee">
          <h3>Coffee </h3>
          <h4>Coffee Flavor</h4>
        </section>
        <section class="ColdDrinks">
          <h3>Cold Drink</h3>
          <h4>Cold Drink</h4>
        </section>
        <section class="HotDrinks">
          <h3>Hot Drink</h3>
          <h4>Hot Drink</h4>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").change(function(){
        $("section").hide();
        $("section" + "." + $('option:selected', this).attr('data-tab')).show();
    })
 });
```